# How do I utilize REST to post GPS data from an Android device into a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, android, rest

I am a student in the process a building an Android app that can post a GPS track into a Rails application.  I would like to do things the "Rails" way and take advantage of the REST.  My rails application basically has 3 models at this point: users, tracks, and points.  A user has_many tracks and a track has_many points.  A track also has a total distance.  Points have a latitude and longitude. I have successfully been able to create an empty track with:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<track><distance>100</distance></track>' http://localhost:3000/users/1/tracks
```

**Whoo hoo!**  That is pretty cool.  I am really impressed that rails do this.  Just to see what would happen I tried the following:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml -d '<track><distance>100</distance><points><point><lat>3</lat><lng>2</lng></point></points></track>' http://localhost:3000/users/1/tracks
```

**Fail!** The server spits back:

> Processing TracksController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-14 00:03:25) [POST]
>     Parameters: {"track"=>{"points"=>{"point"=>{"lng"=>"2", "lat"=>"3"}}, "distance"=>"100"}, "user_id"=>"1"}
>     User Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1)
>
> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Point(#-620976268) expected, got Array(#-607740138)):
>     app/controllers/tracks_controller.rb:47:in `create'

It seems my tracks_controller doesn't like or understand what it's getting from the params object in my tracks_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @track = @user.tracks.build(params[:track])
```

My xml might be wrong, but at least Rails seems to be expecting a Point from it.  Is there anyway I can fix TracksController.create so that it will be able to parse xml of a track with nested multiple points?  Or is there another way I should be doing this entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Track.points=` is a magic method that expects any number of `Point` objects. It adds and removes objects from the collection. You get this behaviour when you define a `has_many` association. This is why you're seeing `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch`.

What you actually want to do is accept nested attributes for the associated collection.

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :points

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :points
end
```

Sending `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will provide you with the `Track.points_attributes` magic method. It expects an array of hashes, where each hash is the attributes for building the nested object.

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<track><distance>100</distance><points_attributes><lat>3</lat><lng>2</lng></points_attributes></track>' http://localhost:3000/users/1/tracks
```

The Rails log may look something like this.

```
Processing TracksController#create
  Parameters: {"track"=>{"distance"=>"100"}{"points_attributes"=>[{"lat"=>"3","lng"=>"2"}]}}
```

[ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) API documentation.

Comment: Wow, this seems like it might work!  Unfortunately, I am now getting an error involving "with_indifferent_access" being called on the value passed.  Any advice?


Processing TracksController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-14 10:46:27) [POST]
  Parameters: {"track"=>{"points_attributes"=>{"lng"=>"2", "lat"=>"3"}, "distance"=>"100"}, "user_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.6ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) 

NoMethodError (undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for "2":String):
  app/controllers/tracks_controller.rb:47:in `create'

Comment: If I change your XML I can insert a single point: "curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<track><distance>1000</distance><points_attributes><point><lat>39</lat><lng>29</lng></point></points_attributes></track>' http://localhost:3000/users/1/tracks"
Unfortunately, this doesn't work for 2: "curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<track><distance>1000</distance><points_attributes><point><lat>39</lat><lng>29</lng></point><point><lat>39</lat><lng>29</lng></point></points_attributes></track>' http://localhost:3000/users/1/tracks"
How do I format the XML for 2?

Comment: Okay, I think I've go it now. The following XML seems to work.  
<track>
    <distance>1000</distance>
    <points_attributes>
            <lat>39</lat><lng>29</lng>
    </points_attributes>
    <points_attributes>
            <lat>2</lat><lng>5</lng>
    </points_attributes>
</track>
YEAH!  Thank you soo much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I realise now that I forgot to give an example with many points. Looks like you worked it out anyway! :-)